# git produces no output when called from script via cron (log/shortlog)

Tags: bash, git, cron

I've got a script `git-test` going to a local git repo and calling `git shortlog` to keep track of recent changes. For testing purposes, I just used these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /myrepo.git
result="$(/usr/bin/git shortlog -3)"
echo "$(date):$result" >> /tmp/git-log
```

the crontab entry is

```
* * * * * /home/username/git-test >> /tmp/cron-output 2>&1
```

After all the script **IS WORKING called from console** and **IS WORKING from cron with doing a simple `ls -lh`** instead of the git command. But it IS NOT WORKING called from cron with the git command. So the problem must be git.

I tried:

1. calling script from terminal -> doing fine, getting git short logs
2. calling script from cron, like above -> no git output in `/tmp/git-log` and no errors in `/tmp/cron-output`
3. calling script from cron, but doing a `$(ls -lh)"` instead of `$(/usr/bin git shortlog -3)` -> doing fine
4. calling script from cron, writing to a file directly with `git shortlog -3 >> /tmp/git-log` -> no git output in `/tmp/git-log` and no errors in `/tmp/cron-output`
5. putting the git `cd /myrepo.git;git shortlog -3 >> /tmp/cron-output 2>&1` directly in crontab -> no output and no errors in `/tmp/cron-output`

Any Ideas what the problem might be?

Thank you!

Comment: Adding a `set -xv` at the beginning of your script can help you debug what the script is/isn't doing, and adding  `env` command may let you see if there is something in the Cron environment that is tripping you up or that is significantly different from your regular command line.

Comment: Thank you for the tipps - they'll be useful for me working with cron in future! Problem was solved by using other git options (see below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git shortlog` has a weird "feature".  [**It is documented**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog), right up front in the manual page, but the "feature" is *so* surprising that it is often missed:

> If no revisions are passed on the command line and either standard
> input is not a terminal or there is no current branch, git shortlog
> will output a summary of the log read from standard input, without
> reference to the current repository.

Your run from crontab has stdin redirected to a file (well, to `/dev/null`, but "not a terminal") so you hit this feature: `git shortlog` reads the log from stdin, and that's empty, so its output is empty.

The cure is to feed it the appropriate `git log --pretty=short` output, as seen in the **SYNOPSIS** line in the documentation.

(Why the "feature"?  I have no idea.  I don't understand this behavior at all.)

Comment: This indeed did the trick. Thank you very much, great job! Never thought that kind of problem could be documented in the manuals.